# Immigrating from South Africa to Australia

Tags: australia, south-africa

Is it better to work directly through the Australian embassy or to work with an immigration lawyer in order to move from South Africa to Australia? I have heard horror stories from people who used lawyers before. If you have moved from SA to Aus, and was using a lawyer, how long does this process take you? If you did all the manual work yourself, how long did it take?

Comment: Hi Pls refer the following source http://www.saaustralia.org/index.php/topic/9251-the-100-step-process-to-immigrating-to-australia-from-south-africa/

Comment: Hi - this is a very good source, but does not answer my question of whether to use a lawyer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would help us answer your question if you wrote about which type of visa you are considering?

Nonetheless, the process is quite simple and easy to follow using skillselect and immiAccount. Better do it yourself and save on the exorbitant fees these lawyers/ agents charge. In either case, the time required to get the visa depends on the visa type that you applied for, and on per-case basis. Using a lawyer/ agent does not help speed up the process in any way.

Comment: Hi @kpatil. I would need to work in Australia and live there. So - I am not sure what I need, but your answer answers my question well enough. Thanks.

Comment: Well, then permanent residency visas (sub-class 189 or 190) seem to be the best fit for you. Study these visa types at border.gov.au and see if you are eligible. These visas will allow you to live and work in Australia indefinitely (although there are some travel restrictions after 5 years, but most probably, you will apply for citizenship before 5 years). These visas also have the most benefits- like Medicare, free access to public schools (for kids), etc.